# AI vectorize Bunting Labs

Tags: qgis, plugins

I have been testing Bunting Labs new AI Vectorize plugin and not having much luck.  I am a Geologist, making maps by pencil annotating on clear film over stereo photos then digitizing the overlays. I have been successfully using Raster Tracer which gives you some control over coloured lines, etc.  But...the AI doesn't seem to have any means of controlling what I want, it just goes where it wants to.  Has anyone got it sorted?  I will eventually talk with Buntings but wanted to see if anyone else has had some experience. Hans van der Kwast has tried it but it doesn't look like it is a good as Raster Tracer apart from the ability to polygonize.